# After Georeferencing the jpg file using GDAL, Can I know which pixel of the jpg file has been moved to which pixel of the tif file?

Tags: python, coordinates, gdal

Fist of all, I'd like to say thanks to everyone who will give me answer.

I wanna get the geo-coordinates of each pixel of the drone image(jpg).

So I did georeferencing on drone image(jpg) using GDAL and GCP info.

And it also got the geo-coordinates of each pixel of tif file obtained through georeferencing.

But what I wanna know is the geo-coordinates of each pixel of jpg file.

So I have to find which pixel of jpg was moved to in tif.

Can I know which pixel of the jpg file has been moved to which pixel of the tif file?

Here is the code and pre-georeferencing image (jpg) and post-georeferencing image (tif)

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = gdal.Open('data/DJI_0165_cali.jpg')

gcp_list = []
gcp = gdal.GCP(392689.698, 294905.073, 0, 3702, 970)
gcp_list.append(gcp)
gcp = gdal.GCP(392727.269, 294776.388, 0, 1981, 996)
gcp_list.append(gcp)
gcp = gdal.GCP(392765.136, 294638.506, 0, 283, 988)
gcp_list.append(gcp)
gcp = gdal.GCP(392732.312, 294639.35, 0, 391, 615)
gcp_list.append(gcp)
gcp = gdal.GCP(392703.634, 294770.92,0, 1996, 698)
gcp_list.append(gcp)
gcp = gdal.GCP(392670.438, 294885.556,0, 3519, 669)
gcp_list.append(gcp)

ds_gcp = gdal.Translate('output.tif', ds, GCPs=gcp_list)
ds_gcp = gdal.Warp('output.tif',ds_gcp, dstSRS='EPSG:3857', dstNodata = np.nan)

def pixel(file,dx,dy):
    px = file.GetGeoTransform()[0]
    py = file.GetGeoTransform()[3]
    rx = file.GetGeoTransform()[1]
    ry = file.GetGeoTransform()[5]
    x = dx*rx + px
    y = dy*ry + py
    return x,y

pixel(ds_gcp,1500,1500)
```

**pre-georeferencing image (jpg)**

[image]

**post-georeferencing image (tif)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called `GDALGCPTransform` in the C++ API:
https://gdal.org/doxygen/gdal__alg_8h.html

As far as I know there is no Python binding but it seems that it is present in `rasterio`: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html

You can run it on the dataset that is the output of `gdal.Translate`.